# kue/ how to restrict concurrent active jobs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kue

i have issue, i set by default concurrent(1)

```js
    function execute(){ 
      queue.create(title, {
        title          : title + ' id(' + reportId + ')',
        options        : options,
        criteria       : criteria
      }).save();

      return new bluebird((resolve) => {
        queue.process(title, function(job, done){
          doExecute(job.data.options, job.data.criteria).then((rows) => {
            done();
            resolve(rows);
          })
        });
      });
    }
    .....
    return execute() // event click to add new job
```

but, when i add new job by execute(), i see new job in kue active list and again add, again, i just can add them unlimitedly in active list, all of they execute concurrently in spite of i set by default concurrent(1).

it's pefect for me, if would each job gets in kue inactive list first and then gets in active list by 2 or 1, how i set it